# Is it possible to use asm-x.x.jar in Google App Engine when using Spring Framework?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, aop

If I include asm-x.x.jar in my Web application, I get errors. Errors can be removed by removing asm-x.x.jar from the classpath. But I need to use Aspects in my app, so I have to have asm-x.x.jar in my classpath. Are there any work arounds for this problem?

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2527

Comment: You should be more specific regarding what you mean by errors.  Knowing what the errors are could help us find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, apparently this should work if done correctly.

http://www.ardentlord.com/apps/blog/show/829881-spring-3-0-on-google-app-engine